# MySql seems to changing the way it treats string variables

Tags: mysql

For quite some time I've been writing ad hoc queries against our database that look like this:

```
USE db_name;
SET @entity_name = 'EntityName';
SELECT *
FROM data d JOIN entities e ON d.entity_id = e.id
WHERE e.name = @entity_name;
```

This was working fine for quite some time. Recently, I've found that this query has terrible performance, where the query would not return. I was able to fix the issue by switching to this:

```
USE db_name;
SELECT CONVERT('EntityName' USING LATIN1)  INTO @entity_name;
SELECT *
FROM data d JOIN entities e ON d.entity_id = e.id
WHERE e.name = @entity_name;
```

The `name` column is VARCHAR(45), with latin1_swedish_ci collation, and if I run:

```
USE db_name; SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

I get latin1, latin1_swedish_ci

I'm not sure why suddenly the optimizer needs a hint as to what type/collation the variable should be in order to find the correct index.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something changed coinciding with the point when the query ceased to have good performance. MySQL upgrade? Configuration change? did you used to run `SET NAMES latin1`? Did the table get more rows? Did you change the table definition or storage engine?

Comment: Variable is not database object, so there is no relation between variable and database collations.

Comment: Rows were added, but no table changes. There was a minor version change to DB, but I’ve never run into this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general problem.  `'EntityName'` is coming in with some character set and collation, presumably established in the connection parameters or `SET NAMES`.

But then the Optimizer, in spite of usually being happy to convert the constant to the characteristics of `e.name`, seems to fail to do so when using an @variable.

I recommend you file a bug with bugs.mysql.com and post the link here.

PS.  @@character_set_database and @@collation_database are not relevant; please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`